# How return null by using Stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

So, I have an `ArrayList` of autogenerated strings. I want to find the first element that contains some character or else if there is no one element that matches this filter, to apply another filter. In another way, I want to return `null` object.

So I write this lambda expression:

```
str.stream()
   .filter(s -> s.contains("q"))
   .findFirst()
   .orElseGet(() -> str.stream()
                       .filter(s -> s.contains("w"))
                       .findFirst()
                       .orElseGet(null))
```

But if there is no one element that matches this two filters I will have NullPointerException. How, can I get something like: `return null`?

Comment: Don't. Instead, return an `Optional` and let the client decide what to do with it.

Comment: but think about it, you really want to return that `null` so that you move the problem further? May be a default value? or even better throw the exception earlier?

Comment: @Eugene using FP and null... it's not the best option, but if you have to, I'd prefer to throw the exception prior rather than handling null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An additional, simpler approach: you can filter on strings containing `q` or `w`, then sort to move those containing `q` first, find first, return null if the optional is empty:

```
str.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains("q") || s.contains("w"))
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.contains("q") ? -1 : 1 )
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

`.sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.contains("q") ? -1 : 1 )` will move the strings containing `"q"` first. Since the stream has been filtered only on values containing either `q` or `w`, then returning null will only happen no element is retained.

Comment: I thought about this, too complicated :(

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'll second this, I wanted to edit my answer with sort of like this, but since you posted...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I would prefer it as I'm sure to traverse the stream only once. It's a better alternative for large streams.

Comment: @ernest_k *unless* measured, this is called guessing, no offense

Comment: @Eugene Of course, that's why I said it's just an alternative. But wouldn't you choose to have just one traversal even if it's a small stream?

Comment: @ernest_k, I support the idea of iterating once (added it to my answer), but, IMHO, filtering complicates things

Comment: Upvoted, definitely a better approach as the traversal is done one time no matter what the content is.

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, simply `.orElse(null)` instead of the last `orElseGet`. `orElseGet` accepts a `Supplier` and you pass a `null`, calling `get()` on a null reference, well...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is [`Optional::orElseGet(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) which accepts a [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and throws the `NullPointerException`.

Use the [`Optional::orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) which accepts `T` which is `String` in your case.

The following code works:

```
List<String> str = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String output = str.stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.contains("q"))
                   .findFirst()
                   .orElseGet(() -> str.stream()
                                       .filter(s -> s.contains("w"))
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .orElse(null));                 // <-- HERE

System.out.println(output);    // Prints null
```

---

Alternatively, use the [`Optional::orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) to return `null`. The `Supplier` itself must be not `null`:

```
.orElseGet(() -> null));
```

Answer (score 3):

`orElseGet` expects a `Supplier`, you need to pass a value, which is the case for `orElse`.

I wouldn't use Stream API here, one iteration is enough to solve the problem:

```
String wString = null;
for (String s : str) {
    if (s.contains("q")) return s;
    if (s.contains("w") && wString == null) wString = s;
}
return wString;
```